# Search a column for multiple "true" contents and return another cell value to a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to search each column of data for the "true" content, then return the adjacent code from column "E", then have it return the results at the bottom of column "G" in the first instance, then same for "H" and so on.

The result will be a list of numbers, where "true" was found in that column.
I believe this can be done but is a step too far for me.

[crop from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q04DM.png)

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? Excel 365 can do it easily.

Comment: its 2013, having 365 installed over weekend.

Comment: Googled, textjoin is not supported with 2013 edition. doh!!

Answer (score 1):

In Office 365:
`=FILTER($E$1:$E$10,G$1:G$10=TRUE)`

Or if there are multiple TRUE's possible:
`=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER($E$1:$E$10,G$1:G$10=TRUE))`

In older versions (confirm array-formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`):
`=INDEX($E:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(G$1:G$10)/(G$1:G$10=TRUE),1))`

Or for multiple TRUE's possible (also `ctrl+shift+enter`):
`=TEXTJOIN(",",1,INDEX($E:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(G$1:G$10)/(G$1:G$10=TRUE),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUM(--(G$1:G$10=TRUE)))))))`

Or better: `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,REPT($E$1:$E$10,G$1:G$10=TRUE))`
(Uncertain and unable to test if it requires entering with `ctrl+shift+enter`)
Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564652/12634230

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I found that the single report work, although I tweaked it to extend over the whole list =INDEX($E:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(G$4:G$230)/(G$4:G$230=TRUE),1))  However the multiple return has a invalid name error.  =TEXTJOIN(",",1,INDEX($E:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(G$4:G$230)/(G$4:G$230=TRUE),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUM(--(G$4:G$230=TRUE)))))))    i think it maybe in the $a$a ref????

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZznb.png (I have semicolon separators due to language settings on the computer used for testing).

Comment: The $A:$A reference is to index the column. The `SUM` part returns the count of TRUE's. So if there are two TRUE's it returns `A2`. This is being used as a counter in the `ROW` function, which then is `ROW(A1:A2)` returning an array of {1,2} for the aggregate/small function

Comment: Thanks for looking again, i've realised =textjoin is not a function on Excel2013. 365 is being installed over weekend so all should be good next week. Fingers crossed. thx again