# How to separate unique values in column and put all corresponding rows in a single row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that looks something like this-

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |

And I want to convert it to this -

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2,3 |
| B | 1,2,3 |
| C | 1,2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your provided example data, and assuming a data setup like this:

[image: Sample data]

- In cell D2 and copied down is this formula to get unique items: `=INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$9),0))`
- In cell E2 and copied down is this formula to get the joined values: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,REPT($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=D2))`

Adjust the ranges to suit your actual data.

Comment: Nice use of `TEXTJOIN` and `REPT` does this require to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` in Excel versions prior to Office365? I used this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72563510/12634230

Comment: @P.b That's an excellent question, unfortunately I don't actually know if it would require array entry on an earlier version of Excel :(